# External (internet) Pub Sub

Tags: c#, redis

Lately I started to think about a solution to publish messages across the internet to subscribed clients I have. Our system is developed in C#.

We tried to use Redis, it works very good in terms of speed and accuracy, but very bad in terms of security, everyone can subscribe to everything, and the best I can do is:
1) Rename core-functions so they'll be unusable
2) Add authentication (but its per server, not per client)

I have 2 questions:
1) Can I do more in terms of Redis security? Can I set password per subscriber? per channel?
2) Are there any other solutions any of you is aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Redis has no access control whatsoever almost (but just the generic AUTH), and even the planned ACL feature does not include explicit support for subscribing / posting to specific channels.

However... there is a surprising simple thing you could do, if you disable MONITOR and other commands that can be used in order to listen to other clients connections, which is, to use an HMAC in order to hash together the logical channel name with the password in order to obtain the real channel name, which is unguessable to clients that don't know the password.

This is the schema (but you should carefully consider if this is secure depending on your exact setup, connections encryption, set of enabled commands. I can just guarantee that it's crypto-hard to obtain the channel name, and that no channel name can be guessed at random).

For example the password for channel "foo" is "bar". To obtain the channel name you do:

```
HMAC-SHA256("bar","foo") -> 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c05124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
```

And you have your channel name.

IMPORTANT: Note that N clients with the same wrong (old) password will still be able to communicate. This should not be a problem in most setups since they can communicate anyway in this case just subscribing to the same channel name.

IMPORTANT2: If this is over the internet, you should tunnel all this over SSL or a VPN.

IMPORTANT3: On top of all that, make sure to also use AUTH as an additional authentication layer.

Comment: Thanks for the replay! you helped! so as a summary: 1) Remove unused/risky commands. 2) encrypt channel name. 3) use AUTH on top of that. 4) use SSL on all communications. I can add also 5) to add whitelist ip list in the server's firewall. would you add anything else?